.desktop file executing .sh script containing a docker run command not working
I have a .sh script that executes a docker run command inside of it to start a containerized application. The script when executed directly works just fine starting the container and app inside it. However I want to be able to run it from the start menu as with any regular program so I have created a .desktop file for it.
When I try to run it a sound (probably failure sound) is played in the OS and and icon appear next to mouse cursor as well as on the task manager but it does not start. They both go away after a few seconds.
I have just used a .desktop file I have used before for other apps I once grabbed online so bear with me if something in it doesn't make sense.
Example my-script.sh
docker run -d --rm \
  ...
  my-image:latest

Example .desktop file
[Desktop Entry]
Actions=NewWindow;
Categories=MyApp;
Comment[en_US]=123
Comment=123
Exec=/path-to-script/my-script.sh
Icon=/path-to-icon/icon.png
Keywords=myapp
MimeType=
Name[en_US]=MyApp
Name=MyApp
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=marktext
Terminal=false
Type=Application

I do not know if this is possible but I am hoping there is some configuration that can be added/changed in the .desktop to make this work or possibly some other workaround. Anyone has any ideas?

This seems more like a question about how desktop managers run scripts, which would be better asked in [unix.se].
